# Pydrake - How to output reaction forces from plant

Tags: python, drake

How do I evaluate the output spatial force reaction forces?

Currently I have the following implementation:

```
simulator_context = simulator.get_mutable_context()
reaction_forces_output_port = plant.get_reaction_forces_output_port()
plant_context = diagram.GetMutableSubsystemContext(plant, simulator_context)
reaction_force_vec = reaction_forces_output_port.Eval(plant_context)
spatial_force = reaction_force_vec[int(man_suc_joint.index())]
```

How do I evaluate the components of this spatial force?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "evaluate" the spatial force? You already evaluated the port so the returned spatial force has already been calculated. It contains 6 elements, the first three are the reaction torque and the last three are the reaction force.

Comment: @Sherm Well if I print spatial_force[0], I get the error: TypeError: 'SpatialForce_[float]' object does not support indexing. How exactly do I output the exact values of the forces and torques that the spatial forces comprise of.

Comment: See the Python API (sorry it's a bit cluttered at the moment): https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.multibody.math.html#pydrake.multibody.math.SpatialForce_.SpatialForce_[float].get_coeffs

Comment: See also C++ API: https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_spatial_vector.html#a929ee35f2e827f504f3557b18b3c40c8

Comment: Great, thanks for the help! Another follow up question would be: How do I get these values continuously throughout the sim. I assume it's through the logger so LogOutput(plant.get_reaction_forces_output_port(), builder)? but this doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: actually I think figured it out. I used: plant.DeclareVectorOutputPort('reaction', BasicVector(3), get_reaction_value) where get_reaction_value calculates the value

Answer (score 1):

Per discussions on the original post, I believe what you're looking for is the following:

- `SpatialForce.get_coeffs`
- `SpatialForce.rotational`
- `SpatialForce.translational`

I posted some links to the API in comments above.